# How can I refer to an installed client certificate inside a curl call?

Tags: windows, curl, x509certificate, x509, client-certificates

Using C#, it is possible to provide a client certificate that is already installed, in a web request. If a property such as subject of thumbprint is known, then it can be selected and used in the request. A known file path of the certificate file is not needed. [Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1uAhSt) is an example.

I want to do the same with Windows curl.

For example, something like this pseudocode.

```
curl GET https://www.somekindOfaRESTAPI.com -ThumbPrintOfClientCertificate XXXXXX
```

Is something like this possible? It would be highly surprising if I need C# to do a simple GET call with a client certificate. Windows curl should also enable me doing this. But how?

Answer (score 0):

First the environment variable to force SCHANNEL SSL backend must be set.

```
set CURL_SSL_BACKEND=schannel
```

Then the certificate thumbprint can be passed to curl in a way like this:

```
--cert "CurrentUser\\TrustedPeople\\12345abcdefghijk"
```

The same thing with libcurl would be adding the following at the top of the code:

```
curl_global_sslset(CURLSSLBACKEND_SCHANNEL, NULL, NULL);
```

and then loading the certificate with:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, "CurrentUser\\TrustedPeople\\12345abcdefghijk");
```